# Carrierwave/Fog - Undefined Method 'Defaults' for Excon:Module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, carrierwave, fog

I'm stuck. I'm using carrierwave/fog to implement a simple image upload system. Here is my uploader:

```
class OfficeImagesUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  # Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
  include CarrierWave::RMagick
  # include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  # storage :file
  storage :fog

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
```

Here is my fog_init:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {
    :provider               => 'AWS',                               # required
    :aws_access_key_id      => ENV['AWSKEY'],                       # required
    :aws_secret_access_key  => ENV['AWSSEC'],                       # required
    :region                 => 'us-east-1'                          # optional, defaults to 'us-east-1'
  }
  # config.fog_directory  = 'temp-cm'                                 # required
  config.fog_public     = false                                     # optional, defaults to true
  # config.fog_attributes = {'Cache-Control'=>'max-age=315576000'}  # optional, defaults to {}
  # config.asset_host   = 'https://assets.example.com'              # optional, defaults to nil
end

CarrierWave.configure {|config| config.fog_directory = 'office-classifieds-development'} if Rails.env.development?
CarrierWave.configure {|config| config.fog_directory = 'office-classifieds-test'} if Rails.env.test?
CarrierWave.configure {|config| config.fog_directory = 'office-classifieds-production'} if Rails.env.production?
```

And here is the image model to which I want to upload images:

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :office_listing_id, :image, :remote_image_url

  belongs_to :office_listing

  mount_uploader :image, OfficeImagesUploader
end
```

I encounter two problems. When I try to create an image by doing

Image.create(image: 'someurl.jpg')

the image is not created, the image attribute is never filled in with a url, and I get this error: "can't convert nil into string."

This kinda makes sense, I assume I'm running into errors because :image is meant to be an uploaded file. However, when I try the same thing but substitute remote_image_url for image, I get this error:

```
undefined method `defaults' for Excon:Module
```

I have NO idea what this means. Thoughts?

Comment: Each error in Ruby has a backtrace. Please include them, there's no way to guess WHERE those errors happen.

Comment: Also, could you let us know what versions of carrierwave/fog/excon you are using? The backtrace will likely also include this, but otherwise you should be able to find it in your Gemfile.